# notepad++ handling / converting binary command characters

Tags: binary, command, character, notepad++

I'm using notepad++. i want to copy my code and then paste it in a simple textarea of little program (which obfuscates variables, removes blank lines & comments) and returns it.

the problem is my code contains binary command characters (like the NUL in white writing with black background) which the program cant handle.

my questions is, is there a simple way to convert these command charachters into something safe, run the program, and then convert them back?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SynWrite editor this converting of NULL char can be done. Synwrite has text-converters (`Run` menu): described in help file topic.

PSPad has similar text-conv feature (`Tools` menu).

Or you can use a regex to replace `[\x00-\x19]` with new string.